# How can I write a For loop function to run several regressions and store the results?

Tags: r, for-loop, regression, apply, broom

**Help I would like to request:** I am trying to automate a sequence of tasks in a loop. Basically it is running a series of regressions, storing the results and exporting (writing) it into a csv file.

**Issue:** 
I have tried many times to run a “For” loop. I couldn’t figure out how to create and name new variables for each regression based on the current_date column

**Description of data:**
[Link to dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vI-iwpMo-2cGem_X6ABNMwGYTaIil2xc/view?usp=sharing)
It is a dataset of US states in a tabular format (somewhat similar to Tidy Data). 
Each Row or observation refers to a specific state at a specific date.
Each column refers to an attribute of the state 
**Task:**
Main problem: Automate the process of running a series of regressions, storing the results by date and exporting (writing) it into a csv file.

Sequence of tasks:

1. Run the regression

   2. Use broom to tidy the regression results  (coefficients, std errors and p-vale)
   3. Store the results by a specific date
   4. Repeat regression for another date
   5. Use broom to tidy the regression results  (coefficients and the model)
   6. Store the results of the co-efficients (coeff, std error, p value) by a specific date
   7. Store the results of the regression models (R-square etc.) by a specific date

…..
Finally, export all the results in a CSV file

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
for(i in 1:length(current_date)){
    lmtest <- lm( outcome_var [[i]] ~ cumulative_var1_at_current_date + key_cat_var1, data = testdata)
    coeff_results<-tidy(lmtest)
    model_results<- glance(lmtest) 
    write.csv(coeff_results, “C:\\Users\\....combined_results.csv”)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a loop in this context does not make sense to me. Also, the date doesn't seem to affect the output of the regression. Do you want something like that:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
current_date <- Sys.Date()
lmtest <- lm( outcome_var ~ cumulative_var1_at_current_date + key_cat_var1, data = testdata)
coeff_results <- tidy(lmtest)
model_results <- glance(lmtest) 
write.csv(coeff_results, paste0("coeff-results-", current_date, ".csv"))
write.csv(model_results, paste0("model-results", current_date, ".csv"))
```

If not please give an example of what is the `current_date`, and how your data are affected by it.

**After Clarification on the purpose of the current date:**

So basically, you need to loop through the unique dates in the `current_date` column. Then, you have to keep the data that correspond to each day. Here is a solution.

```r
testdata$current_date <- as.Date(testdata$current_date, format = "%d/%m/%y")
all_dates <- unique(testdata$current_date)

for(i in 1:length(all_dates)) {
  lmtest <- filter(testdata, current_date %in% all_dates[i]) %>% 
    lm( outcome_var ~ cumulative_var1_at_current_date + key_cat_var1, data = .)
  coeff_results <- tidy(lmtest)
  model_results <- glance(lmtest)
  write.csv(coeff_results, paste0("coeff-results-", all_dates[i], ".csv"))
  write.csv(model_results, paste0("model-results", all_dates[i], ".csv"))
}
```

Probably there is a more elegant way through subset in lm, but I personally prefer `dplyr::filter` because it gives you more control.

Comment: Thanks. To answer your question on how the data depends on the "current_date" -
the "outcome_var" has specific value attached to each date. 

The variable "current_date" includes dates ranging from last week of February to first week of May. It includes the date for each day. I would like to run the regression for each date. Example:
Regression for Feb 25, Feb 26, Feb 27 etc.

Comment: Follow-up after the clarification:
The code worked - thanks! 
It took me some time to figure out some issues with the date. The `format = "%d/%m/%y"` wasn't working properly and showed "NA" no matter what I tried.

----

**Additional request**
May I also request you to explain the rationale behind using the "unique" function and looping through `current_date %in% all_dates`? This way I will learn how to run similar codes in future. I also noticed that there are couple of threads in Stackoverflow, I can post a comment there as well.

Comment: You may have some mixed date formats (for example 1/6/2000 and 1-6-2000), so `as.Date()` may not be able to parse properly, hence the NA. You can also try `dmy()` function from the `lubridate` package to parse with multiple formats. As for the second question, you don't need to run through the same date twice, because it will be repetitive and it will overwrite the previous one. That why I use `unique()` to get all the unique dates. Now, because you compare a scalar(all_dates[i]) with a vector(the current_date column) you can not use equality `==`,  instead you need `%in%`.